# How to quickly switch between two apps on one half of the split-screen view?

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, recents-screen

I'm in this scenario a lot:
I'm using split screen opened to App1 taking the first half of the screen and App2 taking the second half of the screen. I frequently need to switch between App2 and App3 on the second half of the screen while keeping App1 on the first half. One way to switch between them is to tab the *recent apps button* then *drag* the app window to the second half of the screen. Unfortunately this process takes from 5 to 15 seconds each time I want to switch between App2 and App3, which is very exhaustive as I need to switch between them in a very frequent manner (About 3 to 10 times within 5 minutes).

How could I switch between App2 and App3 on the second half of the screen quickly just by some gesture and the apps get instantly switched without the need to drag or re-position the apps windows in order to re-fit the split screen each time?
A gesture example could be: swiping from the buttom edge of the screen to upwards on the second half of the screen (if screen is in horizontal mode).

**Important clarification:**
I'm asking about switching apps while being in multi-app split screen view. I'm not asking about single app view.
One example of apps which works very well for the single app view is [EAS App Switcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.echoff.easyswitch). What I need is that when I switch to another app it's opened in the second half of the splitted screen (not the full screen which destroys the split screen view). 
Let me clarify more. I have App1 and App2 active (in split screen mode). EAS will do the job if it replaces App2's window with App3's while keeping App1's as is. What it does is that it opens App3 on full screen (single app view) destroying the split-screen view and App1 becomes in the background instead of keeping App1 active and next to it is App3 on the other screen half.
It would be very helpful if exist some app or launcher that achieves this.
I'm on Android 6.0.1 on Samsung Note 4 with root access.

Comment: I have tested on Android Marshmallow, but it activates app in single app mode every time. I have also checked the setting and it seems there's nothing related to split-screen. It would be termendously great if it really supports split-screen on Marshmallow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion that works perfectly on a galaxy s5, and I'd assume that it's the same on a note 4.

While in split screen, long press on the back button. You'll now see all available apps on the left side of the screen. Drag the wanted app to the bottom part of the screen.

It's not as fast as you wanted, but it's two steps which would take less than 1.5 sec. when you're used to it.

**Edit:**

Found even a better way. Open app 1 and 2, now long press on the back button, and scroll to the bottom, you'll see an option called "create" press on that, and it will save the two apps as your preference. Now do the same while having app 1 and 3 open. Now to switch between the two, long press on back button, and you'll see the preset opting on the top left of the screen.

Comment: Wow. It's amazing. The only remaining struggle is holding the back button delay time. If there exist a way to a have a floating side movable button like in EAS app switcher to instantly switch between apps by tabbing, that will be the exact thing I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm unaware of a better way, but I'm sure this makes it MUCH faster then the way you had before...  I'll definitely be in the lookout for a better one.